# Hightlight effect with animation for `ComboBoxItem`s

Tags: wpf, animation, combobox, triggers, mouseevent

I want a simple animation effect on the background of `ComboBoxItem`s in the `ComboBox` element. The items should highlight with the defined color when the pointer is over it and revert to its original state when the pointer leaves.

This is my template

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                        Padding="2"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.01"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                                To="#FFA7ACD4" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.6"
                                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                                To="White" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{DynamicResource ColorItemSelectedBackground}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have a hunch that triggers is the way to go.
I've tried using `VisualSateGroups` with both `MouseEnter` and `MouseOver`.
`MouseEnter` did nothing and `MouseOver` didn't revert to its original state.
I recon this example reflects best on what I want to achieve.

WPF is not new to me but I find dependency objects very confusing. Especially with the multiple approaches available for manipulating or animating properties.
There is a `NullReferenceException` upon opening the dropbox. Which is clear to me. There simply isn't a dependency object linked to the storyboard, but in this approach, I can't set the `TargetName` property inside a `Style` trigger.

What's the right approach for this? If using `VisualSate` is the "native" approach, then I would prefer this over triggers.

**UPDATE**

This works, but it uses triggers. I would prefer a solution using `VisualStateGroups` just for learning purposes.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.01"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="#FFA7ACD4" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>

                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.6"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="White" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                        Padding="2"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                        Background="White">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{DynamicResource ColorItemSelectedBackground}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                                    Padding="2"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                    Background="White">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Common">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                        To="White" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                        To="#FFA7ACD4" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" 
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: That works great, but the only issue with this is that the storyboard in `Common` > `Normal` overrides the storyboard in `SelectionStates` > `Selected`. The visual hint for the selected item isn't re-applied after the mouse leaves. Any ideas?

Comment: Move the Selected state to the Common group.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. However I do not understand. If that's what's required, then why does the `SelectionStates` group even exist?

Comment: Sorry, the MouseOver doesn't work if Selected is inside the Common group

Comment: It does for me. The selected item won't be highlighted when the mouse moves over it though. This won't work. If you want flexibility, use data triggers with multiple conditions.

Comment: If I simply move `Selected` into the `Common` group, the storyboard in `MouseOver` doesn't start/play anymore. Meanwhile I read that your suggestion is as close as it gets and that it's simply not possible to automatically return to `Selected` from `MouseOver` using the `VisualStateManager`. I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As a side note to mm8's answer. It's the only way to highlight selected items and highlight items under the mouse pointer.

The `VisualStateManager` doesn't appear to be able to return to the `Selected` state because it is overwritten by the `Normal` state.

Therefor, I've removed the `VisualStateManager` in favor for a multi-trigger approach.

```
<Color x:Key="ItemBackground">White</Color>
<Color x:Key="ItemSelectedBackground">#FFC5CBF9</Color>
<Color x:Key="ItemMouseOverBackground">#FFA7ACD4</Color>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <!-- Trigger for hightlighting items on MouseOver -->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.01"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="{StaticResource ItemMouseOverBackground}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>

                        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="{StaticResource ItemBackground}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <!-- Trigger for hightlighting selected items on MouseOver -->
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true" />
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.01"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="{StaticResource ItemMouseOverBackground}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>

                        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                    To="{StaticResource ItemSelectedBackground}" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                <Border 
                    x:Name="Border"
                    Padding="2"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                    Background="White">
                    <!--<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ItemBackground}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ItemMouseOverBackground}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ItemSelectedBackground}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="{StaticResource SelectedUnfocusedColor}" />
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>-->
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```